# Lags of an ACF plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to produce `acf` plots using `ggplot2`. My code is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
x = lh
conf.level = 0.95
ciline = qnorm((1 - conf.level)/2)/sqrt(length(x))
bacf = acf(x, plot = FALSE)
bacfdf = with(bacf, data.frame(lag, acf))
ggplot(data=bacfdf, mapping=aes(x=lag, y=acf)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "identity") + 
  ggtitle("Orders")
```

With this I am able to produce a `ggplot2` `acf` plot of autocorrelations with lags that range from zero up to 20.

How can I edit this to have `ggplot2` plot lags ranging from -10 through 10 instead?

I essentially used the code from this source to come up with my code posted above: http://ask.programmershare.com/387_17805747/

Comment: Why would you have negative lags? It is an autocorrelation of a serie with itself. You only get negative lags when you do cross-correlation between two time series.

Answer (score 2):

[Autocorrelation function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185521/measuring-dependency-of-subsequent-points-from-markov-chain/185524#185524) for lag = 1 is [calculated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10947/formula-for-autocorrelation-in-r-vs-excel/10948#10948) as

```
mx <- mean(x)
sum((x[1:(N-1)] - mx)*(x[2:N] - mx)) / sum((x-mx)^2)
```

for lag = -1 the only thing that would change is `x[1:(N-1)]` and `x[2:N]` changing their places. It is *symmetric*, so comparing `x[t]` with `x[t-h]` is the same as `x[t+h]` with `x[t]`, because the idea is to compare *t*-th value with another value that is distant by *h* steps.